# iOS - cellForRowAtIndexPath Code Explanation

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview

Here is the entire Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DetailCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSUInteger sectionIndex = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger rowIndex = [indexPath row];

    NSDictionary *section = [self.sections objectAtIndex:sectionIndex];
    NSArray *rows = [section objectForKey:@"rows"];
    NSDictionary *row = [rows objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    cell.textLabel.text = [row objectForKey:@"label"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.myManagedObject valueForKey:[row objectForKey:@"key"]] description];
    return cell;
}
```

My question is about:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [row objectForKey:@"label"]; 
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.myManagedObject valueForKey:[row objectForKey:@"key"]] description];  //This is NSDate
```

1. Why is this code using two different formats:  objectForKey & valueForKey?
2. why is there not a need to call self.myManagedObject with objectForKey?
3. What's the purpose of description?

Comment: objectForKey is what you generally use to access an NSDictionary.  valueForKey is for "key-value coding" which is a generalized mechanism for accessing fields in a non-dictionary using dictionary-like syntax.  For "description", look it up in the [NSObject spec](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this code using two different formats: objectForKey &
>   valueForKey?
>
> why is there not a need to call self.myManagedObject with
>   objectForKey?

`self.myManagedObject` is an `NSManagedObject`. There is no `objectForKey:` method for `NSManagedObject`.

`row` is an `NSDictionary` type. `objectForKey:` is a dictionary method.

> What's the purpose of description?

`[self.myManagedObject valueForKey:[row objectForKey:@"key"]]` should be returning an object  which will contain a `NSString` type property as `description`.

They just as a single line. you can split up it to multiple lines as follows

```
YourCustomClass *customclassObj = [self.myManagedObject valueForKey:[row objectForKey:@"key"]];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = customclassObj.description;
```

Comment: Thanks.  What about Question 2:  why is there not a need to call self.myManagedObject with objectForKey?

Comment: what is self.myManagedObject datatype ? dictionary  or something else ?

Comment: Using `valueForKey:` in this context allows a level of indirection to apply to generic class objects (that implement KVC).  The dictionary (row) contains a value which specifies which property to access on `self.managedObject`.  So if the value in the dictionary were `@"thingy"`, you could think of the second line as as accessing `[[self.managedObject thingy] description]`, where thingy is some attribute of the class.

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObject *myManagedObject;

Comment: @sapi  Why did we not have to call self.myManagedObject called for objectForKey ?

Comment: @user1107173 - because `objectForKey:` is a dictionary method (similar to dictionary[key] in other languages).  `valueForKey` works on any object that implements KVC.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        //create new cell
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }



    [tableView setRowHeight: 50.00];

    UILabel *name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 70, 30)];
    name.text=@"Ajay";
    [cell.contentView addSubview:name];
    [name release];

   // cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    //cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    UIButton *btn1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 5, 70, 30)];
    //UIButton *btn1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    //btn1.frame=CGRectMake(80, 5, 40, 30);
    [btn1 setTitle:@"Name" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(Nam:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn1.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    [[btn1 layer]setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    [[btn1 layer]setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn1];
    [btn1 release];

    UILabel *add=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 56, 70, 50)];
    add.text=@"Biliya";
    [cell.contentView addSubview:add];
    [add release];

    // cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    //cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    UIButton *btn2=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 56, 70, 30)];
    //UIButton *btn1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    //btn1.frame=CGRectMake(80, 5, 40, 30);
    [btn2 setTitle:@"Address" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn2 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(Nam:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn2.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    [[btn2 layer]setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    [[btn2 layer]setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn2];
    [btn2 release];




    return cell;

}
```